How do I use paymaster in safe protocol kit?
I am trying to set up a safe account using the safe protocol kit. I was able to create a safe account using typescript interface. Now the thing is when I am trying to create a transaction, I want my pre-deployed paymaster to pay the gas for the mentioned transaction. I am aware that I can use gelato as a relayer for this specific task, but is there a way I can directly use paymaster? Is there anything I am missing here? Please let me know.
Thanks.

Hey we released a series of documentation pages dedicated to sponsor transactions using 4337. We also released a speicific guide to do so using Pimlico.
Let me know if it answered your question! Best, Louis
